# UniFi CloudKey controller gen1 gui on port 443 won't accept username and password

Tags: ubiquiti

So, as the title say I can not log in CloudKey management page on port 443, username and password are not accepted, but on the device management page, on port 8443 those same credentials are accepted.

Is there a way to tshoot this? Fix it? Or the only solution is factory reset of the controller and uploading the backup configuration?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The password for the controller and the CloudKey management page, can be different. But I had the same problem and found no other way to solve it, than the Factory reset ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

This is a wide question. In my experience, it could be because the mongo-db is full. You need to flush the database. It's a known error.